# Why is the output from these parallel processes not messed up?

Tags: bash, shell, multiprocessing, execution

Everything is executing perfectly.

words.dict file contains one word per line:

```
$ cat words.dict
cat
car
house
train
sun
today
station
kilometer
house
away
```

chapter.txt file contains plain text:

```
$ cat chapter.txt
The cars are very noisy today.
The train station is one kilometer away from his house.
```

This script below adds in result.txt file all words from words.dict not found with **grep** command in chapter.txt file, using 10 parallel **grep**:

```
$ cat psearch.sh
#!/bin/bash --
> result.txt
max_parallel_p=10
while read line ; do
  while [ $(jobs | wc -l) -gt "$max_parallel_p" ]; do sleep 1; done
  fgrep -q "$line" chapter.txt || printf "%s\n" "$line" >> result.txt &
done < words.dict
wait
```

A test:

```
$ ./psearch.sh
$ cat result.txt
cat
sun
```

I thought the tests would generate mixed words in result.txt

```
csat
un
```

But it really seems to work.

Please have a look and explain me why?

Comment: Maybe because `$nb_parrallel` and `$nb_parralel` are distinct, unrelated variables?  The spelling is `parallel`, incidentally.

Comment: grep is super fast, and your input is small - maybe they're just finishing in sequence.

Comment: AFAIK the output of a thread as mentioned in your case will first be fired if he has got everything together and not somehere in the middle of it. That's because you use an `%s` instead of an `%c`. But I'm not 100 % sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background jobs are not threads.  With a multi-threaded process then you can get that effect.  The reason is that each process has just one standard output stream (stdout).  In a multi-threaded program all threads share the same output stream, so an unprotected write to stdout can lead to garbled output as you describe.  But you do not have a multi-threaded program.

When you use the `&` qualifier bash creates a new child process with its own stdout stream.  Generally (depends on implementation details) this is flushed on a newline.  So even though the file might be shared, the granularity is by line.

There is a slim chance that two processes could flush to the file at exactly the same time, but your code, with subprocesses and a sleep, makes it highly unlikely.

You could try taking out the newline from the `printf`, but given the inefficiency of the rest of the code, and the small dataset, it is still unlikely.  It is quite possible that each process is complete before the next starts.

Comment: You wrote:
> There is a slim chance that two processes could flush to the file at exactly the same time,

I understand that parallel flushes would produce mixed content.

Finally, multiple streams (multiple processes) could generate mixed content. in first section you were saying multiple write on different streams are protected. Could you put these in another way to make me understand?

You wrote:
> but given the inefficiency of the rest of the code,

Super !! 

Do you have in mind a different version that you could share?
Or would you like to elaborate this particular point?

Comment: OK.  The standard output streams are protected, but the file position (EOF) with the append could conceivably be the same.  It is highly unlikely though.  You are creating multiple other processes, such as `wc` and `jobs`, these will allow the previous `fgrep` to complete.  I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but if it is to demonstrate the problems of concurrency then a shell is a bad tool to use.  Better to use a multi-threaded language.

Comment: I would like to understand why the words in result.txt are not mixed up.

I will edit the question to add a modified version with new data and new test based on your remarks in order to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: @Jay:  perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve here, and why you expect them to be mixed-up.

Comment: To be sure that there will never be mixed chars, another version could make each printf write in a dedicated file. At the very end a final cat could display the result. I understand from your answer that the version in the question might produce mixed output, so it is unsafe. It cannot be observed with few tests because the situation is very rare.

Comment: @Jay:  correct!  The only thing you can be sure of about the order of background job completion is that it is unsafe.